# MySQL: How to manually raise net_read_timeout and net_write_timeout error

Tags: mysql, timeout

I want to know the difference between MySQL net_read_timeout and net_write_timeout setting.

I have gone through official MySQL documentation site but it's not enough information for me to go on. Is anyone able to give me advice on how I can recreate one or both of these errors at will, so that I can experiment with the issue and come to understand the differences between them?

Answer (score 0):

According to this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_read_timeout  and my intuitive understanding of my experience with these errors, these timeouts occur when a connection reaches the predetermined value set in the global variable `net_read_timeout` and `net_write_timeout`.  If you want to artificially reproduce them, one way might be to set those values very low, and then attempt to conduct operations on your database.  This will cause the timeout errors to occur after much shorter 'windows' of time, thereby causing the error to occur much more frequently. These values, I believe, will need to be edited in your MySQL configuration file, usually my.ini

Comment: i set timeout value to both variables of 1 seconds and hit select query as "select sleep(30)"  but still not able to produce the exception.

Answer (score 0):

net_read_timeout should be the time to wait for the full query to be sent, while net_write_timeout should be the time to consume the result after the query is done, not the maximum time allowed to run the query.